# How to get the sender id or sender name(url, uri, ect..) of soap request in ServletFilter?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, servlet-filters, http-request

I'm implementing web services, there are a client and many web services in the system. Here is my scenario, a **client** invokes web service **A** (so it sends the soap request to A) in order to satisfy the client's request, **A** needs to invokes another web service (**B**). Each invocation needs to check the authorization first, So I would like to know who makes a calls and I don't want to pass the sender id as a parameter of services.
For example,

- `Client1` invokes service `A`
- `ServiceA` invokes service `B`
- ect...

I use `Servlet Filter` in order to intercept http request and I try to get informations from http header but I couldn't find any information about the sender. For the invocation from the **client**, I can find the username from sessions/cookies, but I couldn't find anything in the invocation from **A**.

So I would like to know how we can get the sender of soap request or http request in this situation. Any suggestion?

Comment: How is service B invoked from service A? Do you use something like Apache HttpClient?

Comment: I call service B by the `invokeBlocking()` method disponible in `RPCServiceClient` Class.